# Can thread ID be 0?

Tags: linux, proc, thread

While traversing `/proc/$PID/task/` directory, my program sometimes (rarely) comes across a subdirectory with name `0`. After I notice this and check the directory, there's no such subdirectory already.

This raises a question: can a thread Id (which I believe makes up the content of `/proc/$PID/task/`) be zero? Or is it not a thread Id but something else?

Comment: (For Windows, no https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms686746(v=vs.85).aspx)